# Setting custom headers in PDF.JS requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, pdf.js

By Default `Pdf.js` library https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ does not set `X-Requested-With` headers needed to identify if incoming request is ajax or not, I needed it to add in my application for some reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled but didn't find any answer and at last solved it myself by digging into pdf.js library code

find this line

`this.httpHeaders = (this.isHttp && args.httpHeaders) || {}`

in `pdf.worker.js` under `NetworkManager` and change it with

`this.httpHeaders = (this.isHttp && args.httpHeaders) || {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}`

and you are done, if someone has cleaner code than this are welcome to share.